# How to set browser tab title and add icon

Tags: reactjs, browser, tabs, navigation, native

I am using [react navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/) and see that the chrome browser tab title is getting set to the name of the particular navigation screen.  Is there anyway to override the title to something else, and maybe also add an icon?

I do see that I can change a navigator screen name, however each name has to be unique, and I want the browser title to be just one static value and not change from screen to screen.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do all this :

**1 - Add a browser tab title and keep navigation titles**

In this example below, I use the createStackNavigator function from "@react-navigation/stack" :

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function Navigator() {
  return (
     <NavigationContainer>
-      <Stack.Navigator >
+      <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ title: "My application name here" }}>
         <Stack.Screen
           name="Home"
+          options={{ headerTitle: "My Home" }}
           component={HomeScreen} />
         <Stack.Screen
           name="Details"
+          options={{ headerTitle: "My Details" }}
           component={DetailsScreen} />
       </Stack.Navigator>
     </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
export default Navigator;
```

**2 - Add an icon to the browser tab title**

I doubt there is a way to do it using react native libraries. Hopefully, the javascript "document" object is available in React, so we can add the icon to the browser tab this way :

```
 export default function App() {
+  // On android and iOS, trying this block of code will fail and go to the catch block.
+  try {
+    // Select the <head> tag under <body>
+    const headTag = document.querySelector("head");
+    // Create the <link/> tag.
+    const icon = document.createElement("link");
+    // Create the rel="" attribute
+    const attributeRel = document.createAttribute("rel");
+    // Assign the value "icon" to the rel attribute so that attributeRel becomes rel="icon"
+    attributeRel.value = "icon";
+    // Create the href="" attribute
+    const attributeHref = document.createAttribute("href");
+    // Assign your application icon path to the href attribute so that attributeHref becomes href="path/to/my/icon"
+    attributeHref.value =
+      "path/to/my/icon";
+    // Set the rel attibute to <link> so that the icon JS object becomes <link rel="icon"/>
+    icon.setAttributeNode(attributeRel);
+    // Set the href attibute to <link> so that the icon JS object becomes <link rel="icon" href="path/to/my/icon"/>
+    icon.setAttributeNode(attributeHref);
+    // Insert the <link [...] /> tag into the <head>
+    headTag.appendChild(icon);
+  } catch (e) {
+    //Browser tabs do not exist on android and iOS, so let's just do nothing here.
+  }
    return <Navigator />;
 }
```

Here are some screenshots of the result ("path/to/my/icon" has been replaced with       "https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/favicon.ico" so that you'll see the stackoverflow icon in the screenshots below):

[image: Home Screen]

[image: Details Screen]

[image: The icon in the DOM]